# How to find the roots of a nonlinear function

Tags: analysis, roots, nonlinear-system

I need to find the roots of this function :$ f(x)=e^{dx}(cos(ax)+sin(ax))-bx+c$ where $b,c\in R$ and $a,d>0$. Using Desmos, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xix9o5lhon?lang=it  it's possible to see a pattern for the zeros independently of the values of the parameters. How can I find such zeros?

Comment: At big $x$ exponent is prevailing over linear function, that is why roots tend to be close to roots of $\cos ax+\sin ax=0$, then big roots $x\approx \frac{(4k-1)\pi}{4a}$, $k\in N$